# how to stop 'Upgrade to windows 11' process in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

A few days ago I accidentally click 'Update and shutdown', turns out since then, my Windows 10 downloads Upgrade for to Windows 11 in Settings > Update & security.

[image]

My workaround is to pause the updates longer than 7 days, I set the duration in Settings > Update & security > Advanced Options.

But how to cancel the Upgrade process permanently until I decide that I want to upgrade to Windows 11?

Answer (score 1):

Since the update process has started, you cannot (to the very best of my knowledge) permanently block the update at this point.

Probably the best approach now, is to allow the update to happen (nothing will be lost).

Then go to Windows Update and right away, roll back to Windows 10.

Then be careful of the update.

I have a Windows 11 machine that started as Windows 10 and the first time I ran the machine I clicked on I do not want to upgrade and it did not.

I changed the main SSD drive, started back up and this time I clicked on I want to upgrade and it did.

So you do have a choice, but you need to make sure you do not allow the update to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can block the Windows 11 upgrade using several methods listed in this article:

[How to Stop Windows 11 Update (Block It Forever)](https://www.easeus.com/knowledge-center/stop-windows-11-update.html)

Comment: solution #2 on the above page seemed to solve the problem.  
(I was stuck with it giving me only choice of "Upgrade and Restart" (no choice to just restart or shutdown). Followed #2 instructions, restarted, and it came up still as Windows 10.